# how to get an image that is obtained in the iteration of resources in a template?

Tags: angular

in the result of calling an api, I get, among other data, a data that is a url to an image, this url points to a resource that is protected, so to list it I make the request from a service.

sample response

```
[
    {
        imageUrl: 'https:some.domain.com/resources/sample.png'
    },
    {
        imageUrl: 'https:some.domain.com/resources/another-sample.png'
    }
]
```

In this task I must list each image in a table, to this end I try the following

template

```
<table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let resource from resources">
            <td>
                <img
                    [src]="getImageFromSource(resource.imageUrl)"
                    [alt]="resource.name"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tbody/>
</table>
```

component

```
getImageFromSource(imageUrl: string): any {
    return this.s3Service.getResource(imageUrl).pipe(
       take(1),
       switchMap(async (a) => this.s3Service.getSourceFromBlob(a))
    );
}
```

The previous code does not execute a call, I understand this call will be made when I subscribe

In this context, what is the correct way to perform this task?

Comment: Did you mean `*ngFor` instead of `*nfFor`?

Comment: yes, it is a typographical error, I have written the whole example in the SO editor. it is already corrected